# Unity3dでプロジェクト内のファイルの順番がバラバラになってしまった

Tags: unity3d

Unity3dで、Project内のpngファイルが元々名前順でソートされていたはずなのですが、いつの間にか順番がバラバラになってしまいました。

名前順に戻す方法はあるでしょうか。

(追記)
ファイル名は単純な数字の羅列です。
41030500101
92600400404
51010500403
等といったように、不規則な順番に並んでいます。

- Windows 7 Service Pack 1
- Unity 4.6.0f3 free

Comment: ファイル名にどのような文字列を用いているか示すべきです。

Comment: 該当ファイルのパスに日本語等、マルチバイト文字列が含まれていませんか? `例：C:\ユーザ\ほげ\もげ\Project\Assets...`

Answer (score 1):

通常は名前順でソートされます。このソート方法を変更することは出来ないので、意図していない動作かもしれないですね。一度「Reimport All」を実行してみるのはどうでしょうか。

Comment: Reimport Allを実行した所、
途中何度か「Opening file failed」というメッセージが表示されました。

Opening file library/metadata/7d/7d~~ failed:
の後に文字化けした内容が表示されます。
ファイルがソートされない件と何か関係はあるのでしょうか。

Comment: > 文字化けした内容が表示されます。

具体的に、どういった文字化けが表示されたのでしょうか？
関係があるかどうかは提示してもらわなければ分かりません。